# Clean list iteration with forEach when multiple actions happen on each element

Tags: java, list

I want to know how can I improve my code. I have method with Map and List as arguments, in this map I have String as a key and some object (eg. Room) as a value.
List contains some other types of objects (eg. House).

Some fields from the Room are empty. I want to fill these fields using parameters from House.

List and Map have the same length. I want to get field from House and put it in the Room from the list which has code from House as key.

I know how to do it for one parameter, so I am using almost the same code for every other parameter( IntStream.range(...)), is there a better way to do this?

```
public class Room {
    String colour;
    String name;
    int size;
    //other fields, getters, setters...
}

public class House {
    String colour;
    String name;
    String code;
    int size;
//other fields...
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<House> houses = Arrays.asList(
            new House("shouldBeA", "A", 12),
            new House("shouldBeB", "B", 32),
            new House("shouldBeC", "C", 43),
            new House("shouldBeD", "D", 54)
    );
    Map<String, Room> rooms = new HashMap<>();
    rooms.put("A", new Room("a"));
    rooms.put("B", new Room("b"));
    rooms.put("C", new Room("c"));
    rooms.put("D", new Room("d"));

    range(0, rooms.size()).forEach(i -> rooms.get(houses.get(i).getCode())
            .setName(houses.get(i).getName()));

    range(0, rooms.size()).forEach(i -> rooms.get(houses.get(i).getCode())
            .setSize(houses.get(i).getSize()));

}
```

Comment: I'm not totally convinced this question doesn't belong on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - check it out. It's a great site for in depth *coding* advice, as opposed to problem-solving advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to shorten your logic in the face of repetition. Streams are nice and `range` is convenient, but when you want to do multiple changes to each element, and the changes are **not** mapping, but rather mutation, then streams are a little weak. This is especially true because you're really iterating over two collections in parallel, so you want to keep track of a lot of **state** (the object in each list, at the relevant index). Streams are not good at state (because they come from functional programming, where there really isn't that much state). Here's what I would do, instead of:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ...

    range(0, rooms.size()).forEach(i -> rooms.get(houses.get(i).getCode())
            .setName(houses.get(i).getName()));

    range(0, rooms.size()).forEach(i -> rooms.get(houses.get(i).getCode())
            .setSize(houses.get(i).getSize()));

}
```

Do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ... (same as ... above)

    for (House house : houses) {
        Room room = rooms.get(house.getCode());

        room.setName(house.getName());
        room.setSize(house.getSize());

        // ... any other settings
    }
}
```

You *could* stick to contents of the loop above into a `houses.forEach()` call, but it would be an ugly lambda - again, because to do a good job you have to keep track of `house` and `room`. In this case, the `for` loop is the cleanest way to avoid looping over `houses` multiple times.

Comment: Thx! Right, I was too focused to do it on stream. You are right. In this case for loop would be simpler and clearer